# AWS-Cognito or AWS SSO, which one should I choose

Tags: amazon-cognito

We are planning to setup three applications, two of them are based on WordPress, and third one is based on Magento. We will deploy these three apps on AWS. We are looking for a tool to centralize the management of all the users for these three apps. We could grant different privilege and allow the different users have different right to these three apps. So, we should choose AWS Cognito or SSO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both if you go with cognito route. Cognito User pools handles your user management (registration, login, granting tokens) while Cognito Identity Pool lets you use any of the identity providers including user pool to exchange tokens for temporary aws credentials based on what role you have attached to the group of users. 
Identity pools also accept SSO with 3rd part authentication providers (federated identity). You can sign in users on your user pool using social identity providers (facebook, google, amazon) or create one using Auth0.

Comment: Thanks, Ninad! Your answer is definitely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cognito is the right fit for your application. AWS SSO is essentially a layer between active directories and services like Cognito or Firebase. AWS SSO helps in delegating access to AWS services and provides SAML/Oauth gateways connected to the active directories.

AWS Cognito on the other hand, allows you to easily integrate your login systems with any auth providers like AWS SSO, Okta, Auth0 and social media channels too. Hence, definitely considering your requirements, AWS Cognito user pool is the best fit.

Comment: Thanks, Abhishek! Your answer is definitely helpful!